# How to build boost::asio example?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to build an example of boost::asio

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

but without any luck.

System: Windows Vista, Visual C++ 2008 Pro, Boost 1.43.

I've added to the project, at VC, the include path and the additional lib path (see note #1), yet the linker gives me this error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib'
```

What do I do next?
In the documentation (the "getting started" part) it says that some boost's components must be built separately. Ok.
How do I do this and where do I find them?
In the "getting started" page there's the section "6.1 Link From Within the Visual Studio IDE". It just tells me how to link, and not how to build it.

Anyone can shed some light? Because I am definitely missing something here.

Note #1: There's not "boost_1_43_0/lib" folder but a "libs". The doc needs a refresh.

Comment: Can you find the file "libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib" in the libs folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889394/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-system-vc90-mt-gd-1-43-lib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this, I needed to re-phrase in order to get an answer:

[fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889394/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-system-vc90-mt-gd-1-43-lib/)

Thank you all!