# Does it make sense to compile Boost yourself on the target platform?

Tags: c++, boost

I have an application that uses Boost. I've just downloaded the precompiled DLL and that's it. Now I think that I probably should compile Boost myself so it can use advantages of the target system. I only need to run software on one system, this is a 2 processors Xeon E5 and so probably the compiler can do some optimizations. Does it make sense?

Comment: If you think it makes sense to use boost, then it is reasonable to build it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2889394/286260), I believe it's still relevant, to you as well.

Actually when you know how, it's very easy to build it.
And yes, **I'd build it unless HIGHEST performance is not a must**.

Good luck!

Comment: then the question is - what compiler options should I use to have highest perfomance...

Comment: you should use standard bjam build - it is rather smart to autotune itself. but it is also not very straightforward to tune manually

Comment: @mvp is correct, the compiler is smart enough to tune itself against the environment's configuration, to a certain degree.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling Boost is not for faint of heart and is not really worth your time doing it. Easiest way to get Windows software compiled against Boost is to install [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/download/).

Comment: not right now - supported configurations are listed on boostpro page I linked above