# Building bjam for boost 1.54 - "skipped 894 targets"

Tags: c++, boost

I followed the advice in this post to install bjam for boost 1.54 on Windows:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889489/997112

However, when I execute bjam.exe from the console I get a final message of:

> skipped 894 targets

I just want to get boost full installed as I want to use regex and I get LINKER errors.

Note to boost community- one word: "installer" !!!!

Comment: The linked question indicates a Windows platform, is that your platform too? There are plenty of installers on other platforms. `brew install boost` on Mac OS X, `yum install boost` on some Linux distros.

Comment: @SamMiller I am Windows too

Comment: You don't need those (3 years old) advices, just read "Getting Started" (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#invoke-b2). Building boost with MSVC on Windows is as trivial as invoking `bootstrap`, `b2 --build-type=complete stage`.